# is there any way to make this code shorter?

Tags: c#

```
//list the controls from the  main form
foreach (Control c in Controls)
{
    if (c is ComboBox)
    {
        ((ComboBox)c).SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
    else if (c is TextBox)
    {
        ((TextBox)c).Text = "";
    }
    else if (c is CheckBox)
    {
        ((CheckBox)c).Checked = false;
    }
    //etc. with FIFTY different types to check against
}
```

Comment: well in C# 7 (in development) it can certainly solve a problem like this... but for today's version, not so much.

Comment: what is the goal here?

Comment: i need to do this job for 50 controls ....

Comment: @fre3land You have 50 *types* of controls, or 50 controls of these three types?  If you have 50 different *types*, then yes, you really need a better pattern, if you have 50 controls of these three types, the code you have should be sufficient.

Comment: 50 types of controls sir.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary It is, however, a bit annoying to read through as the programmer.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary True, and it looks like Domysee had the same (`?.`) idea so I'm deleting the comment.

Comment: You can also remove the `{ }` of your `if`-statements and the enters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this method to set the properties of your controls:

```
public void Set(object obj, string property, object value)
{
    //use reflection to get the PropertyInfo of the property you want to set
    //if the property is not found, GetProperty() returns null
    var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(property);
    //use the C# 6 ?. operator to only execute SetValue() if propertyInfo is not null
    propertyInfo?.SetValue(obj, value);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
foreach (Control c in Controls)
{
    Set(c, "SelectedIndex", -1);
    Set(c, "Text", "");
    Set(c, "Checked", false);
}
```

Comment: This helps ,thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn't that going to run all 50 checks each iteration?

Comment: @AIG - indeed, it is so its a perf issue here. I also need to point out that this works for C# 6+

Comment: @AlG yes it will. I admit its a performance issue, but not all operations have to watch for every CPU cycle

Comment: why the code is not working on c#  vs 14 ?

Comment: This is wrong. because `.?` can return null and you cant have null at left side of assignment. thus compile time error.

Comment: Thanks @M.kazemAkhgary for pointing that out.

Comment: @fre3land Sorry, I made a mistake. The updated answer should work

Comment: @Domysee The last solution worked ,thanks :).

Comment: Why not store everything in a data structure, and then exit out of the for loop as soon as a match is found and run?

Answer (score 9):

One way is to add three overloaded methods for specific types, cast to `dynamic`, and make calls like this:

```
foreach (dynamic c in Controls) {
    ClearOut(c);
}
...
private static void ClearOut(ComboBox c) {
    c.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
private static void ClearOut(TextBox t) {
    t.Text = string.Empty;
}
private static void ClearOut(CheckBox c) {
    c.Checked = false;
}
```

Since `c` is `dynamic`, C# would postpone binding of the `ClearOut` method to runtime, giving you a clean-looking code. The downside of this approach is that C# is unable to tell you at compile-time if one of the overloads is missing.

Comment: I don't see why dynamic is needed if all those types derive from `Control`.

Comment: really nice. i didnt know this. but 50 methods isnt going to be short

Comment: it's possible to implement a method like void?

Comment: @ErikPhilips If you use `Control` for `c`'s type, C# would try to make a method binding at compile time, and fail, because there is no overload of `ClearOut` that takes `Control`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ahh yes I was thinking the other way around

Comment: "50 methods wont be short" True , but sometimes that is the best you can get. Also, it is better to handle it per item, then go through 50 checks every time.

Comment: this is only me testing? i get runtime binder exception

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary That's because you've got a control on the list that has no corresponding method, right? You can catch this situation by adding an overload that takes `Control`, and setting a breakpoint.

Comment: you are a genius. yeah i forgot i had button control. it works great now.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a lookup from each supported type to an action that clears controls of that type, you can then add handlers to that lookup for each supported type:

```
public class ControlClearer
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Action<Control>> lookup = new Dictionary<Type, Action<Control>>();

    static ControlClearer()
    {
        AddMapping((TextBox control) => control.Text = "");
        AddMapping((ComboBox control) => control.SelectedIndex = -1);
        AddMapping((CheckBox control) => control.Checked = false);
    }

    private static void AddMapping<T>(Action<T> clearAction)
        where T : Control
    {
        lookup[typeof(T)] = control => clearAction((T)(object)control);
    }

    public static void Clear<T>(T control)
        where T : Control
    {
        //todo support case where T isn't in the dictionary
        lookup[typeof(T)](control);
    }

    public static void Clear(Control control)
    {
        //todo support case where the type isn't in the dictionary
        lookup[control.GetType()](control);
    }
}
```